# AdMob Rewarded Video Ad Screen Orientation

Tags: android, admob

I have a "trivia" kind of game which only allows user to play in "Portrait" orientation. As you know, android activities automatically restarted when the orientation changes.

My game asks 20 questions to user in a randomized order. And there is a button that the user can get "hints" with watching rewarded video ads. However, AdMob sends "Landscape" videos, sometimes. And for that reason, after the video has finished, my activity starts from the 1st question, again.

How can I restrict AdMob from sending "Landscape" orientated video ads? I could not find anything on AdMob help page. Or, can I make it via coding? I am sure that restart thing is about orientation change because when AdMob sends "Portrait" Ads, game goes well from where it was before the video.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: *And for that reason, after the video has finished, my activity starts from the 1st question, again.* that doesn't sound normal. You should probably be asking how to prevent this instead. There is no way to restrict video ads to a specifics screen orientation.

Answer (score 1):

Add "configChanges" property in the activity tag in "AndroidManifest" to prevent "activity" from restarting due to orientation change caused by the intersitial video.

Answer (score 0):

**watching rewarded video** ads start a new Activity then your Activity will be in background and when your video finished or close your Ad then your paused Activity come in foreground.

So don't worry about your App start from beginning. Make sure you're not calling `onDestroy()` on your Activity and having all appropriate configuration in `Manifest` file.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-admob-ads-sdk/BJ9XGyDMGHk